# Does the default action of SIGCONT resume the execution of a stopped process before or after first handling any pending unblocked signals?

Tags: linux, signals

The [POSIX System Interface Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) says:

> The default action for `SIGCONT` is to resume execution at the point where the process was stopped, **after** first handling any pending unblocked signals.

What does "after" mean here? Shouldn't it be "before" instead?
Is there some example to show what it means?

Similarly from APUE:

> Since the process group is orphaned when the parentterminates, POSIX.1 requires that every process in the newly orphaned process
> group that is stopped (as our child is) be sent the hang-up signal
> (`SIGHUP`) followed by the continue signal (`SIGCONT`)
>
> This causes the child to be continued, **after** processing the hang-up signal. The default action for the hang-up signal is to
> terminate the process, so we have to provide a signal handler to catch
> the signal. We therefore expect the printf in the sig_hup function to
> appear before the printf in the pr_ids function.

Shouldn't "after" be "before" instead?

At [order of `SIGCONT` and `SIGHUP` sent to orphaned linux process group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17769300/156458) seems to suggest "before" instead of "after" in the above two quotes, or I misunderstand it:

> The `SIGHUP` cannot be delivered until the child's execution is resumed.
> When a process is stopped, all signal delivery is suspended except for
> `SIGCONT` and `SIGKILL`.
>
> So, the `SIGHUP` does arrive first, but **it cannot be processed until** the
> SIGCONT awakens the process execution.

Thanks.

[When several signals arrive at a process, what is the order between the process handling the signals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635458/when-several-signals-arrive-at-a-process-what-is-the-order-between-the-process)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it means after.  The key is "resume execution *at the point where the process was stopped*".

Signal processing is performed first, and *then* execution continues.

Answer (score 3):

[signal.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/signal.c)
POSIX 1b compliant signal kernel code

Do a search on `SIGCONT`.  You will see that when `SIGCONT` is encountered the code then looks for pending signals.

Comment: Thanks. Could you point out which line in the source file is for "when SIGCONT is encountered the code then looks for pending signals"?

Comment: Try the comments found on lines 661, 862, 2028.  Reading the code is time consuming , so consider starting with comments.  If you search on "SIGCONT" you will find all of the comments and some of the relevant lines of code.